# Sintaxe invalida equação do 2 grau

Tags: python, sintaxe

O erro esta no último else e não consigo identificar, sei que é um erro básico.

segue abaixo o codigo:

```
A = float(input("Qual o valor de A: "))
if A == 0:
    print("Sua equação não é do 2 grau")
else:
    B = float(input("Qual o valor de B: "))
    C = float(input("Qual o valor de C: "))
    Delta = B**2 - (4*A*C)
    if Delta < 0:
        print("A equação não possui raizes reais")
    elif Delta == 0:
        X = -B/(2*A)
        print("Sua equação possui apenas uma raiz e ela é:", X)
    else:
        X1=((-B)+(Delta**(1/2))/(2*A)
        X2=((-B)-(Delta**(1/2))/(2*A)
        print("Existe duas raizes reais que são:",X1,X2)
```

Comment: obrigado! era exatamente a falta de um ()

Answer (score 1):

Está faltando parenteses fechando nestas linhas:

```
X1 = ((-B)+(Delta**(1/2)) AQUI ')' /(2*A)
X2 = ((-B)-(Delta**(1/2)) AQUI ')' /(2*A)
```

O código corrigido fica assim:

```
A = float(input("Qual o valor de A: "))
if A == 0:
    print("Sua equação não é do 2 grau")
else:
    B = float(input("Qual o valor de B: "))
    C = float(input("Qual o valor de C: "))
    Delta = B**2 - (4*A*C)
    if Delta < 0:
        print("A equação não possui raizes reais")
    elif Delta == 0:
        X = -B/(2*A)
        print("Sua equação possui apenas uma raiz e ela é:", X)
    else:
        X1=((-B)+(Delta**(1/2)))/(2*A)
        X2=((-B)-(Delta**(1/2)))/(2*A)
        print("Existe duas raizes reais que são:",X1,X2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nas linhas:

```
X1=((-B)+(Delta**(1/2))/(2*A)
X2=((-B)-(Delta**(1/2))/(2*A)
```

Está faltando uma fecha de parenteses